# Why don't powerline's glyph icons work for me?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I use iTerm2 alongside powerline.  The powerline uses glyphs from patched fonts in UTF-8, and none of them show up in my terminal.  I've tried all the options out there - setting 256 colors for vim, tmux, and iterm.  Using utf-8 for tmux/iterm.  I've tried multiple supposedly compatible fonts.  Nothing works.  How can I get my terminal looking good?

See the circles?  That's where the glyph icons should go.

[image]

Comment: try reinstalling everything. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

This frequently happens to us across various machines. Check the tmux.conf file or the powerline theme to see if those glyphs are correctly rendered in the file. It may be that the Unicode character has broken. Repasting the correct glyph in from a page like http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html ought to work.